# The way of asking questions

Tags: questions

While asking about measurment ,the way of asking confuses me . Because you have to make a very complicated sentence to ask and it is realy hard to traslate it to english word by word .

> To what temperature below zero is this electronic device resistant ?
>
> At what depth can human stay alive?

Are these sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from a missing indefinite article before 'human' in the second sentence, both are grammatically correct. Also the first one is ambiguous because it is not clear whether the limit below zero is approached from above or below.

You are right that they appear to be rather complicated ways of expressing simple idea.

You could reword them to avoid some of the complication:

> what is the lowest temperature that this electronic equipment can withstand?
>
> what is the greatest depth that a human can survive?